# Wordpress/PHP - Namespaces/Autoloader - Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($function) must be a valid callback

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, autoload

I am creating my first plugin entirely from scratch. Whenever I try to add a namespace to the 'template-plugin-activate.php' file, I get the following error:

```
Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($function) must be a valid callback, class "TemplatePluginActivate" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php:292 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\plugins.php(193): do_action('activate_templa...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 292
```

Below are my files. Any help is appreciated.

// inc/template-plugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Inc;

class TemplatePluginActivate
{
   public static function activate() {
      flush_rewrite_rules();
   }
}
```

// template-plugin.php

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'You can\t access this file.' );

if ( file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/vendor/autoload.php' ) ) {
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
}

use Inc\TemplatePluginActivate;

if ( !class_exists( 'TemplatePlugin' ) ) {

    class TemplatePlugin
    {
        //
    }
}

require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'inc/template-plugin-activate.php';
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'TemplatePluginActivate', 'activate' ) );

require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'inc/template-plugin-deactivate.php';
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'TemplatePluginDeactivate', 'deactivate' ) );
```

// composer.json

```
{
    "name": "author/template-plugin",
    "description": "awesome starter plugin example",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "author",
            "email": ""
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Inc\\": "./inc"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code triggering that problem. Also, please explain how this is related to Composer

Comment: The goal is to set up my files so that I can later use the autoload from Composer. BUT, before I do any of that, I must set up the template-plugin.php file the way I want. I want to remove the 'require_once' from the template-plugin.php file, and instead use 'use Inc\TemplatePluginActivate;' instead. Thankfully, by changing the register_activation_hook, I am now able to use 'namespace Inc;' from the 'template-plugin-activate.php' file. BUT, I still cannot get 'use Inc\TemplatePluginActivate;' to work. I still get the same error.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. I had to change the 'template-plugin-activate' file to an uppercase name, so that it could be read as a proper namespace. Same for the deactivation. NOW, the 'use Inc\Activate;' is working.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `register_activation_hook()`.

Your callback is the `activate()` method of the `TemplatePluginActivate` class. That needs to be updated once you introduce namespaces. The class would be `Inc\TemplatePluginActivate`.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'Inc\TemplatePluginActivate', 'activate' ) );
```

Also, your deactivate action is running on activation too. The hook you need is `register_deactivation_hook()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am still not able to use: use Inc\TemplatePluginActivate, in the template-plugin.php file. Am I not using the autoload correctly?